# How to change language of designer files in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, comments, designer

Does anybody know how to change the language of the (automatically generated) designer files in Visual Studio without changing the language of the UI?

Background: the members of my team use german and english Visual Studios. The problem is (svn-) merging the designer files with comments in two different languages. Whenever a member changes a web form, the designer file is re-generated and the comments are changed to the member's language.

Comment: We are still being very annoyed by this issue in VS 2019. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Someone has [asked Microsoft for a new feature for this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/add-language-setting-for-auto-generated-comments/1531942), but it seems they have not understood.

Comment: This feature request was cancelled by Microsoft because of a 'not enough info' status... I think that, to this day, there's no solution to this request. Decided to try to ask for this setting in a new request ticket: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Language-setting-for-auto-generated-comm/10417908

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a straightforward way to do this, but in the following folder (this is for Visual Studio 2010) you'll find a lot of .zip files:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\1033
```

For example **WebForm.zip** contains the following files:

- Default.aspx
- Default.aspx.cs
- **Default.aspx.designer.cs** (this is your bad guy)
- WebForm.vstemplate

These are your Visual Studio template files. You could change them manually to be the same on all developer workstations. Or in your case, you might just want to copy and override the entire folder from an English Visual Studio installation.

Comment: In VS2019 (16.3.0) it is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\<YourEdition>\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\Web Forms\1033\WebForm\Default.aspx.designer.cs`, but it's only used when I create a new .aspx file.